# i have open CV version 4.2 , how i convert it in 1.0.1

Tags: opencv

i have to convert OpenCV version 4.2 into 1.0.1 because I am notable to fix path issues in opencv4 yet I have code which requirements are OpenCV 1.0.1 version.

i am facing this error
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\Ashutosh Bansal\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py:435: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.

help me for the conversion.
thank you

Comment: OpenCV 1.x is extremely obsolete. You can't even find the original source for that version anymore. Your "error" is in fact a Tensorflow warning.  In fact, it's only commenting on certain functionality that will eventually become deprecated so this is not an error in any way.  Your code should still be able to run. Do you mean you want to use **Tensorflow** 1.0.1? That makes more sense than using OpenCV 1.x.  Either way, please provide more context as your supposed error cannot be reproduced at all.  Is there a code snippet that you have to show us?

Comment: https://github.com/ashubansal005/Gender_and_Age_Recognition, this is link.